# MYSQL remote read only access, how do I set it up?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I've seen stuff on how to enable remote access, but never how to restrict it so that users cannot make any changes. I tried doing this:

```
mysql> create user 'dude'@'boingoboingo.local' IDENTIFIED BY '007'; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

This user cannot access any databases remotely. What do I need to grant for read only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql>grant select on *.* to 'dude'@'boingoboingo.local';
```

or only one database

```
mysql>grant select on DATABASE_NAME.* to 'dude'@'boingoboingo.local';
```

Comment: I keep getting access denied though I flushed privileges and changed 'boingoboingo.local' to '%'

Comment: Try change '%' to 'localhost' to access unix local socket

Comment: @Flostsam: That's because you had password required checked you dummy! Thanks for the good answer bindbn!